# After Form submit Javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onchange

After sendign form, it loads main page again but on this screen, my javascript / jQuery validation does not work. It does not print any error to the console.

For example, I try to run some validtion after each on change and I can do it before submitting, however after submitting and reloading page it does not work.

```
$("select[name='mytest']").on('change', function() {

........
});
```

Do I need to change or add anything ?

Comment: This code is not enough to understand the issue.Please share more html and js code

Comment: Add your markup as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bind` to associate the `load` and `change` event together that will then listen to change event and page load event to invoke the same block of code.

```
$("select[name='mytest']").bind('load change', function() {
// this code invokes on both load and change
........
});
```

OR there is also a fix for which you can call the function of page load like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("select[name='mytest']").bind('change', function() {
     // this code invokes on both load and change
      ........
     });
   $("select[name='mytest']").trigger('change');
});
```

This will now trigger the `change` event when the page is loaded. So you can ensure that the code is invoked on page load and of course on `change` event.

Comment: not works, but noticed that ,after submit textboxes and selectbox is coming with entred values, i mean it doesnot load the fresh page

Comment: and this not only for jquery, javascript also doesnot work